# How to make an App working in an background?

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

I am developing an application, in which I am fetching some photos from the XML link using NSXMLParser, so it takes some time to load images into view, while loading if I click on the home button in iPhone (device) and open the application again, the App crashes. I didn't know how to make my app to be able to run also in background state. I googled and found, "App States and Multitasking" but i can't able to make it in my application. Any solutions or links will be appreciated.

Comment: What part of [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) isn't working for you?

Comment: @CarlVeazey Bcoz I am very new to development, i didn't know where to implement all the codings stuff in the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTask = 0;
 UIApplication  *application= [UIApplication sharedApplication];
backgroundTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
}];
```

use this code in your application at initial method

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
//call your upload method
}
```

Comment: I have a small doubt on this, let me clearly explain my question, i have six buttons in my main view, "Gallery" is one of the button, what I did was, when i click on a button, i am parsing XML with the use of NSXMLParser. When I click on "Gallery" button, it takes some time to load, while loading if i press the home button in my iPhone, and reclick on the App Icon, the app crashes.